# Bug in popping up JComboBox and JPopup

Tags: java, windows, debugging, jcombobox, jpopupmenu

I am having a bug I'm having trouble tracking down and was wondering if anyone had seen anything like this.  I am building my code in Java 8.  I run/test this code on both Macintosh & Windows.  This bug only happens on a machine running Windows OS. (Haven't tried linux yet)  I am testing on Windows 8.

I have a JComboBox that is in the same window as a JTable and a JTree which I have modified to add checkboxes.   The JComboBox initially works perfectly. Popups up and works correctly.  But once I interact with the JTable or JTree it no longer functions.  It does not popup anymore.

[image]

When this pane is further added to a JTabbedPane, I can get it functioning again when  tab out of this pane & back into the one with the JComboBox.  In an attempt to go around this bug (and understand it better) I tried using a JPopupMenu instead of the JComboBox.  The bug happens with the JPopup as well and it's easier to tell where it fails.  When I debug I find that I do enter the mousePressed event and everything looks good in the mousePressed event.  But the JPopupMenu.show() function doesn't get executed correctly.

```
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        topDirPopup.show(e.getComponent(),  e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
```

I could show more code but I'm not sure what code is interacting with the popup.

Any ideas?  Any work arounds?

Isolated it down to it's going wrong in the checkboxes in the JTable (or the JTree) but I'm using standard Swing Table so it's easier to isolate.  Very basic code.. doesn't read anything from the file system.  Doesn't do any modifications to swing objects.  Still see the bug.

[image]

I stripped most everything that is useless out of my code.
Main Test Class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Test extends JPanel {

Test() {
     super(new BorderLayout());

     FileSelectionPane fpane = new FileSelectionPane();

     JLabel label = new JLabel("File Selection Pane Test");


     this.add(fpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     this.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}


private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Selection Test Tool");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add content to the window.
    frame.add(new Test());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
            UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
   }
}
```

My FileTool Pane.  Yes I have a BorderLayout within a BorderLayout.  It's silly in this example but my actual code is more complex and I have a Tabbed Pane in between these two.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class FileSelectionPane extends Panel  {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1784004323821479260L;
    /**
     * 
     */ 

    JTable fileTable;
    JComboBox<String> topDirComboBox;


    FileSelectionPane() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

         createTopDirectoryComboBox();

         FileSelectionTableModel tModel = new FileSelectionTableModel();
         fileTable = new JTable(tModel);
         JScrollPane jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(fileTable);


         this.add(jScrollPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         this.add(topDirComboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    void createTopDirectoryComboBox() {
         topDirComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();

         topDirComboBox.addItem("C:\\Test\\Fake");
         topDirComboBox.addItem("C:\\Test\\More");
         topDirComboBox.addItem("C:\\Test\\View");

    }

    public class FileSelectionTableModel extends AbstractTableModel  {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        static final int numCols = 4;
        private String[] columnNames = {"..", "Name",  "Type", "Size", "Creation Date", "Modification Date"};
        private final static int  checkCol = 0;
        private final static int  nameCol = 1;
        private final static int  typeCol = 2;
        private final static int  sizeCol = 3;


        public int getColumnCount() {   return numCols; }

        public int getRowCount() { return 5; }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        // Only the check item is editable.
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
        { 
            return (col == checkCol) ? true : false;    
        }

        Boolean tBool[] = new Boolean[10];

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (col == checkCol) 
                tBool[row] = (Boolean) value;
        }


        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

            Object rtnObject = null;

            switch (col) {
                case checkCol:
                    rtnObject = (Object) tBool[row];
                    break;
                case nameCol:
                    rtnObject = (Object) "Testing";
                    break;
                case sizeCol:
                    rtnObject = (Object) "5";
                    break;
            }

            return rtnObject;
        }

        /* Set up the types of each column  */
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {       
            //   getValueAt(0, c).getClass();

            Class<?> rtnValue = null;

            switch (col)
            {
                case checkCol:
                    rtnValue = Boolean.class;
                    break;
                case nameCol:
                    rtnValue = String.class;
                    break;
                case sizeCol:
                    rtnValue = String.class;
                    break;
                case typeCol:
                    rtnValue = String.class;
                    break;
            }

            return rtnValue;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The failure of a pop-up to appear suggests an exception is happening in the AWT event dispatch thread.  If the same code works on some systems and not others, I'd wonder if you're creating or modifying your components outside of the AWT event disaptch thread (which you're never supposed to do).

Comment: I shouldn't be. I'll look around to see if I might be interrupting the AWT dispatch thread.  I do use SwingWorker in my main application but this happens in test code that doesn't use any background threads that I intentionally create.

Comment: BTW I still have no solution to this.  I ended up retooling this.  I'd really like it if we could find a solution to this bug even if it's a hack.

Comment: I found that calling `setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);` on the JComboBox solved the issue.  Fortunately, on any machine made in the last ten years, the performance difference between lightweight and heavyweight popups is probably negligible anyway.

Comment: Thanks!!  This is exactly what I was looking for. This fix works great!

Comment: @VGR This works great!!  THANK YOU!!!!  While I retooled around this first problem, the next thing on my todo list needed Popups to work correctly.